# GNU screen: move window to other region

Tags: gnu-screen

Say I have created two windows and only then created a second region. How do I move one of the windows (which are both part of the first region) to the second region?

Well actually I just wanted both windows to be shown side-by-side (after their creation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You move the focus to the other region (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>)
2. You activate the desired window in that region (the usual way i.e.

   1. e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>
   2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>"</kbd>

Comment: Ah, argh, all windows are available in all regions. Ok gotcha.